how to reduce the space in gb4e gloss example?
I'm writing a linguistics paper and I use gb4e package. For the sentence below, I don't know how to reduce the space between the two consecutive example sentences. Any other solutions than using \vspace{}.
Here is the code:
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tipa}  
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\usepackage{gb4e} 


\begin{document}

\begin{exe}
\ex
\label{7}
\begin{xlist}
\ex 
\label{7a}
\gll Ali [ men ket-t-im ] di-d-i.\\
Ali [ \textsc{1sg.nom} leave-\textsc{past-1sg} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\
\textsc{Shifted}: \ding{51} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.'
\vspace{-0.3cm}
     
\textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that I_{speaker} left.'\\

\ex 
\label{7b}
\gll Ali [ meni ket-t-i ] di-d-i.\\
Ali [ \textsc{1sg.acc} leave-\textsc{past-3sg} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\
\textsc{Shifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.'
\vspace{-0.3cm}
     
\textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{51} `Ali_{i} said that I_{speaker} left.'\\
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}



\\ not required at the end of the sublist, and the MWE is
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[numbers,sort]{natbib}
\usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tipa}  
\usepackage{tikz} 
\usepackage{tikz-qtree} 
\usepackage{gb4e} 
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}


\begin{exe}
\ex
\begin{xlist}
\ex 
\label{7a}\label{7}
\gll Ali [ men ket-t-im ] di-d-i.\\
Ali [ \textsc{1sg.nom} leave-\textsc{past-1sg} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\
\textsc{Shifted}: \ding{51} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.'
     
\textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that I_{speaker} left.'

\ex 
\label{7b}
\gll Ali [ meni ket-t-i ] di-d-i.\\
Ali [ \textsc{1sg.acc} leave-\textsc{past-3sg} ] say-\textsc{past-3sg}\\
\textsc{Shifted}: \ding{55} `Ali_{i} said that he_{i} left.'
     
\textsc{Nonshifted}: \ding{51} `Ali_{i} said that I_{speaker} left.'
    \end{xlist}
\end{exe}

\end{document}


Note that, I've added the package pifont which supports the \ding command

Thank you very much! I noticed that you did not include \vspace{0.3cm} between the two translations. When I delete \vspace{} between the two translations, there is a space. Any other solutions to achieve that if I don't want to use \vspace{}? Thank you very much.
